# Does `sql-mysql` work on MS Windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, sql-mode

I remember that a few years ago when I tried there was an issue with the mysql client not supporting pipes on Windows or something like that, so it didn't work.

I tried `sql-mysql` with Emacs 27 and it is able to connect to the server, appears to send the query, but the results do not appear in the sql buffer. I seem to remember this was the case before too.

Does `sql-mysql` still not work on Windows?